# Error : Unrecognized vmoption

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage

Unable to resolve this,

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m - 
XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
 Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
'nrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC
 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

Even checked the hyphen-minus ie the en-dash, nothing worked.
Anyone Know about the issue?

Below is the setenv.sh file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


 JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms8192m -Xmx8192m - 
 XX:UseConcMarkSweepGC"

 # memory
 JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"

  # Timezone and JVM file encoding
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=UTC -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"

  # solr.solr.home => solr home for this app instance
  # port => app server port no.
  # hostContext => wepapp context name
  # zkHost => ZooKeeper ensemble host names and its client port no.
  # zkClientTimeout => ZooKeeper client timeout
    ZKSETUP="ZKSETUP_REPLACE"
    #SOLR_OPTS="-Dsolr.solr.home=/home/ci/solr -Dport=8983 - 
    DhostContext=search -DzkClientTimeout=20000" # Local w/o zoo
    #SOLR_OPTS="-Dsolr.solr.home=/home/ci/solr -Dport=8983 - 
     DhostContext=search -DzkClientTimeout=20000 -DzkHost=localhost:9983 - 
     DzkRun" # Local w/zoo
     #SOLR_OPTS="-Dsolr.solr.home=/home/ci/solr -Dport=8983 - 
     DhostContext=search -DzkClientTimeout=20000 -DzkHost=sjc-dev- 
    usrv29.corp.coupons.com:2181,sjc-dev-usrv29.corp.coupons.com:2182,sjc- 
    dev-usrv29.corp.coupons.com:2183" # Cloud Zoo
    SOLR_OPTS="-Dsolr.solr.home=/home/ci/solr -Dport=8983 - 
     DhostContext=search -DzkClientTimeout=20000 $ZKSETUP"

    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $SOLR_OPTS"

   #JMX Config Options
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote - 
    Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 \
       -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false - 
    Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"

    CATALINA_OUT="/home/ci/logs/web/tomcat7/catalina.out"

   # GC, GC Logging Config Options
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps - 
   XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution\
        -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime - 
   XX:+PrintReferenceGC -Xloggc:/home/ci/logs/web/tomcat7"

    LOGGING_CONFIG="- 
    Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/ci/tomcat7/logging.properties"
```

I'm unable to figure out the issue, if I remove concMarkSweepGC, it shows the next config as unrecognized.

Comment: What is the expanded value of `"$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m - 
XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"` ?

Comment: Have added the setenv.sh file, please help me out

Comment: I could solve, it's that i had copied and pasted script , hence windows would add some characters,(which i could not c), used Dos2Unix command and sorted it